# sscanf match double

Tags: c, parsing, scanf

```
sscanf(str, "%lf", &num);
```

Here I try to parse a double. 
It catches `inf` which is fine.
However it also catches `infififi` as `inf`, which is wrong in my case.

Other examples would be `nandoscope` as `nan` and `123abc` as `123`. How to fix this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

That's by design, so it doesn't need fixing. Perhaps you can rewrite your code to read a delimiter after the double, or see if sscanf is reading the whole string.